# Как вывести данные из промежуточной таблицы laravel?

Tags: laravel

Использую отношение hasManyThrough.
Две таблицы , связаны через таблицу Table2 .

Таблица Table2 содержит id Table1 и id Table3.

Нужно получить данные из Table3 и дополнительные данные из Table2 , зная table1_id.

Значение из Table3 получил, а из дополнительные данные из связующей таблицы Table2 получить не могу.

```
Table1  
       id    


Table2                      
       id
       table1_id
       table2_id
       data 


Table3
       id
       info
```

Зная table1_id я  получаю значение info из Table3 , а как получить значение data из Table2 ?

Comment: Насколько знаю hasManyThrough используется чтобы получить информацию через посредническую таблицу, в примере ниже чтобы получить info Table3 через Table2 у которой есть связь через Table1_id и table2_id

https://imgur.com/FO1TWyY
Расскажи какие есть таблицы и что надо

Comment: дописал описание вопроса. надеюсь теперь разборчиво написано

Comment: Самый простой вариант напиши в table1     
`
public function table2 ()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Table2::class);
    }
`

Comment: спасибо. возможно есть способ без дополнительных отношений? В документации написано про метод pivot, но у меня он почему то не срабатывает.

Comment: Вот статья, только там не через hasManyThrough https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/ Я бы мог дать код, но не уверен что будет работать, сам так редко делал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такие таблицы

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    Schema::create('user_car', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('car_id');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->foreign('car_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('cars')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

В модели User стоит:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class, 'user_car');
```

Чтобы получить машины пользователя: `$user->cars`
Чтобы получить pivot: `$car->pivot` (в примере в pivot попадут user_id, car_id)
Насколько знаю чтобы добавить к результату еще pivot столбцы используй: 
`->withPivot('pivot_name1', 'pivot_name2')` после belongsToMany